When Android Gradle plugin 7.5 deprecated on SDK level 34?
We updated SDK from 33 to 34 due to deprecated date from android announcement and found that our AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) version 7.5 is not pass minimum requirements (8.1.1), but we can build and compile normally. Please refer to image and url
Is there a deadline to update the AGP version to meet the minimum requirements?

In my understanding the minimum APG version refers to the Android Studio version, not to the API level. So if your older AS version works fine with the AGP and API level you use at the moment, there should be no requirement to upgrade.
